# datatable select all filtered data not reflecting in UI

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

I am working on a table with data where one of the columns is a checkbox, and the user can check which rows they want to be exported to csv / excel files.

https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/bLp2jz4e/12/

My jsfiddle example works correctly for non filtered data, if the table searchbox is empty and you click the 'select all' column, it will accurately select all and deselect all.
[image]

But if you search for something like 'x', and then click the 'select all' first column checkbox, it selects all results but doesnt reflect the change in the column checkbox?
[image]

My datatable is declared like so:

```
    var myProductGapsTable = $('#myProductGapsTable').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    retrieve: true,  
    "language": { "emptyTable": "No table data availiable."},
    "sDom": 'Bfrtip',
    "paging": false,
     buttons: [
                 {
                     extend: 'excelHtml5',
                     text: 'excel',
                     //exportOptions: {  modifier: {  page: 'current' }  }
                     exportOptions: { rows: { selected: true, search: 'applied' } }

                 },
                 {
                     extend: 'csvHtml5',
                     text: 'csv',
                     exportOptions: { rows: { selected: true, search: 'applied' } }
                 },
             ],
    /*
    responsive: {
        details: {
            type: 'column',
            target: -1,
        }
    },
    */
    columnDefs: [ {
        targets: -1,
        orderable: false,
        searchable: false,
        className: 'control',
    }, {
        targets: 0,
        orderable: false,
        searchable: false,
        className: 'selectall-checkbox',
    } ],
    select: {
        style: 'multi',
        selector: 'td:first-child',
        search: 'applied'
    },
    order: [ 1, 'asc' ],
});
```

And I'm using the following 3 functions to handle the checkboxes and what happens when you click 'select all':

```
    // On DataTables select / deselect event check / uncheck all checkboxes. And deal with the checkbox
// in the thead (check or uncheck).
myProductGapsTable.on('select.dt deselect.dt', function (e, dt, type, indexes){
    var countSelectedRows = myProductGapsTable.rows( {selected: true} ).count()
    var countItems = myProductGapsTable.rows().count()

    if (countItems > 0) {
        console.log("~ countItems > 0")
        if (countSelectedRows == countItems){
            $('thead .selectall-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]', this).prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('thead .selectall-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]', this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    }

    if (e.type === 'select') {
        $('.selectall-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]', myProductGapsTable.rows({search: 'applied', selected: true}).nodes()).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('.selectall-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]', myProductGapsTable.rows({selected: false}).nodes()).prop('checked', false);
    }
});

// When clicking on "thead .selectall-checkbox", trigger click on checkbox in that cell.
myProductGapsTable.on('click', 'thead .selectall-checkbox', function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]', myProductGapsTable.rows({ search: 'applied', selected: true })).trigger('click');
});

// When clicking on the checkbox in "thead .selectall-checkbox", define the actions.
myProductGapsTable.on('click', 'thead .selectall-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
    if (this.checked) {
        myProductGapsTable.rows({ search: 'applied' }).select();
    } else {
        myProductGapsTable.rows({ search: 'applied'}).deselect();
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'select.dt deselect.dt' will be triggered when you click the select-all checkbox. And  countItems is NOT the count of filtered item but the all items. so you should change countItems to myProductGapsTable.rows({search: 'applied'}).count() as below:

```
var countItems = myProductGapsTable.rows({search: 'applied'}).count()
```